# Why doesn't the Bootstrap navbar toggle when the button is pressed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a website with a collapsing navbar.
The button has the correct id.
Jquery and bootstrap are included in the correct order at the bottom of the body.
However when I press the button, nothing happens.

I added additional CSS code to customize my navigation bar. But the navigation bar won't work without the CSS code either, so I'm relatively sure it's not because of that.

Html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Navbar test </title>
    <link href="../img/faviconlogo.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbarnavbar-default navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="" height="40" id="brand-icon-navbar" class="justify-content-center">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site 6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../js/someJavaScript.js"></script>
    <script class="script" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

css:

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 600;
}

#brand-icon-navbar{
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav a {
    display: block;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.nav-item{
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 840px){
    .navbar .container{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        max-width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 840px){
    .navbar .container{
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:835px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-brand {float:none;display: inline-block;}
    .navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item { float: none; margin-left: .1rem;}
    .navbar .navbar-nav {float:none !important;}
    .nav-item{width:100%;text-align:left;} 
    .navbar-toggler {display: block !important;}
    .navbar-toggleable-sm.collapse {display:none !important}
    .navbar-toggleable-sm.collapse.in {display:block !important}
  }

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}
```

Libraries:

- jQuery v3.5.1
- Bootstrap v4.3.1

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tobiasooo/pen/QWqLLmz)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```html
<script class="script" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js" defer=""></script>
```

with

```html
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Replacing the jquery script actually changed something. But still the toggle still doesn't work properly. I made an CodePen so you can see what I mean by that.

Comment: I ran your codepen and found the issue. The media queries you've written are breaking the navbar toggle. Comment out the mqs and it will work fine. No issues with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with importing js. Try the 3rd row from below,

```
 as, <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).